Run-time error '91' object variable or with block variable not set "on executing second code"
Option Explicit

Sub cvt()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Dim url As String
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Let url = "https://cvt.in.telstra.com.au/BILLQA/"

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate url

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = ie.document

doc.getElementById("applicationForm:j_idt70:0:j_idt72:2:j_idt76:1:j_idt79").Click

doc.getElementById("applicationForm:messageTest").Click

End Sub

on this code: while executing below code getting error as below
doc.getElementById("applicationForm:messageTest").Click

i'm getting

"Run-time error '91': object variable or with block variable not set"


My guess would be that there's no Element with that ID, so there's nothing to Click.

If the first click triggers some action which exposes the object for the second click, you may need to wait for that action to complete before trying to find "applicationForm:messageTest"
